# WFFM custom save actions not working on Preview server but fine on CM server in sitecore preview mode

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am using Sitecore 8.1 WFFM Update 3, i have created a new save action and it is working fine on sitecore preview mode in the master datatabase, but on preview server (web database) it is not working, always i am getting error result section of wffm form, i have commented the following on preview server in sitecore.forms.config

```
<hooks> <!—remote events hook--> <hook type="Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHook, Sitecore.Forms.Core"/> <hooks>

<event name="wffm:action:remote"> <handler type="Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHandler, Sitecore.Forms.Core" method="OnWffmActionEventFired" > <param name="actionManager" ref="/sitecore/wffm/wffmActionExecutor" /> </handler> </event>
```

But these configs are enabled on cm server - master database.

and on preview server (web db) i have enabled the below 2 lines in sitecore.forms.config

```
<setting name="WFM.IsRemoteActions" value="true" />

<setting name="WFM.MasterDatabase" value="web" />
```

also i have tried setting the isClient Action checkbox on custom action but still i am getting error section on preview server, Please help me for the same

Comment: And is there an error in the log file?

Comment: I have found no error in log file, as it is not hitting the execute method and when i search as wffm , i got the only error as below Exception: System.InvalidCastException
Message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProviderBase'.
Source: Sitecore.Forms.Core

Answer (score 0):

Tracing through the cause of the issue, it was due misconfiguration of config file in the Preview server.

After disabling the Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.WebAPI.config, the following error message no longer appears and we can see the log from the log file.

Exception: System.InvalidCastException Message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProviderBase'. Source: Sitecore.Forms.Core